# App Crashes when NavigationController is popped!

Tags: objective-c, iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uinavigationcontroller, crash-reports

Below is what I copy/pasted from the Crash Log sent by the client. I am unable to understand what does that mean :s

Apparently it looks like the app crashed when navigating back to a previous screen (and that's what client has reported). What is UIWebDocumentView here?

I need to resolve the crash but I'm stuck here so any help is highly appreciated.

P.S. I'm using iphone sdk 3.0.

```
Date/Time:       2009-09-29 18:16:28.458 -0400
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.0 (7A341)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbbadbeef
Crashed Thread:  4

    Thread 4 Crashed:

        0   WebCore                         0x3588dd74 __ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 288
        1   WebCore                         0x3588e4c0 __ZL18_WebThreadAutoLockv + 52
        2   UIKit                           0x30aea484 -[UIWebDocumentView _responderForBecomeFirstResponder] + 8
        3   UIKit                           0x30978b34 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:fromView:toView:] + 200
        4   UIKit                           0x30978a54 -[UINavigationTransitionView transition:toView:] + 24
        5   UIKit                           0x30974470 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 1604
        6   UIKit                           0x30973d90 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 256
        7   UIKit                           0x309a7468 -[UINavigationController _popViewControllerWithTransition:allowPoppingLast:] + 400
        8   UIKit                           0x309a72c8 -[UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated:] + 32
        9   Snocell                         0x0002ae00 0x1000 + 171520
        10  Foundation                      0x30554062 -[NSThread main] + 42
        11  Foundation                      0x305023f2 __NSThread__main__ + 852
        12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x31d705a0 _pthread_body + 20
```

Comment: Ok,i guess i found the solution. Sharing it in case someone drops here:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS means that the virtual address you're refererencing is not in the page tables or you don't have access. It's a virtual address that you're not allowed to access. For your example address address 0x67696c69 it's likely that this is something that is not a pointer that was treated like a pointer; or your data structure that contains the pointer was free'd and overwritten with other data.

And, then i see WebCore in the log, a component in iPhone WebKit (http://bit.ly/4j4WsN)

Comment: So, what I was doing here, dispalying a website in UIWebView and before it could load completely, popping back to previous view controllers and it CRASHED.

I found that UIWebView needs to have its delegate cleared before you release it; otherwise, if a web request completes after you release the UIWebView, it attempts to call back to the delegate and causes the application to crash.

SOLUTION: I added "myWebView.delegate = nil;" before popping view controller and it's working now :)

Comment: I was having a similar problem -- webView.delegate = nil solved it, just like for you.

Comment: I came here looking for BADBEEF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, i guess i found the solution. Sharing it in case someone else gets into the same situation:

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` means that the virtual address you're refererencing is not in the page tables or you don't have access. It's a virtual address that you're not allowed to access. For your example address address 0x67696c69 it's likely that this is something that is not a pointer that was treated like a pointer; or your data structure that contains the pointer was free'd and overwritten with other data.

And, then i see WebCore in the stack trace in the log (WebCore is a component in iPhone WebKit - *http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit#Components*)

So, what I was doing here, dispalying a website in UIWebView and before it could load completely, popping back to previous view controllers and it **CRASHED**.

I found that UIWebView needs to have its delegate cleared before you release it; otherwise, if a web request completes after you release the UIWebView, it attempts to call back to the delegate and causes the application to crash.

**SOLUTION:** I added the following code before popping view controller and it's working now :)

```
if (webView.loading)
    [webView stopLoading];
webView.delegate = nil;
```

Comment: This fix did not work for me (though I was testing on an elderly iPhone 2G). I just removed the popViewController call instead. Not the cleverest of solutions but it does work, and in some ways it is more logical.

Comment: It turned out that removing the popViewController statement fixed other problems too. I think that it is better not to call popViewController in didFailLoadWithError method.

Comment: Thanks, was helpful to figuring out in giving me the right direction to look into

Comment: Does anyone know if this is a problem with WKWebView?  We implemented this solution years ago, but are now moving to WKWebView and wondered if we should leave this cleanup in place still.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following will be a right approach. Set the delegate to nil first.

```
webView.delegate = nil;
if (webView.loading)
    [webView stopLoading];
```